# Private Variables are accessed by Global functions

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I learning inheritance and scope access in javascript. Hence I wrote a sample program as below.

```
var A = function(){

    var privateVariable = 'secretData';

        function E(){
        console.log("Private E");
        console.log("E reads privateVariable as : " + privateVariable);
        };

        B  =  function(){
           console.log("GLOBAL B");
           console.log("B reads privateVariable as : " + privateVariable);
        } ;

        this.C = function(){
           console.log("Privilaged C");
           console.log("C reads privateVariable as : " + privateVariable);
       };

};

A.prototype.D = function(){
    console.log("Public D, I can call B");    
    B();    
};

A.F = function(){
    console.log("Static D , Even I can call B");
    B();    
};

var Scope = function(){

        var a = new A();

        Scope.inherits(A); // Scope inherits A

        E(); // private Method of A , Error : undefined.  (Acceptable because E is private)
        this.C(); // private Method of A, Error : undefined. 
        D(); // public Method of A, Error : undefined.

}

Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};

Function.method('inherits', function (parent) {
    console.log("I have been called to implement inheritance");
    //Post will become lengthy. Hence,
    //Please refer [crockford code here][1]
});
```

My Doubts are :

1. Any undeclared variable like B will be in Global Scope. Whether accessing privateVariable via B is bad style of programming? (Because, privateVariable cannot be accessed just like that.) 
   If so, why javascript allows such definitions and access.
2. I want C and D to be inherited.But it is not working for me? Where I went wrong?
3. For fun purpose, I tried classical inheritance as given in [crockford page](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html#sugar), But whether professionals will use classical inheritance in production code ? Whether it is advisable to do so, (because in conclusion,crockford regrets for trying to implement classical inheritance in his eary days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your first question: This is no longer possible in strict mode.

Second question:
`Scope.inherits(A)` adds all properties of `A` to `Scope`, not to `this`. So `this.C` does not exist at that time. You have to call `Scope.inherits(A)` **before** you create a new instance of `Scope`.

`D()` calls a function named `D`. But there is no such function. You only have `A.prototype.D`. If you want to call this method you can do it with `this.D()`. And again: `this.D()` would not exist at that time.

Third question:
It's a personal choice. I suggest - for any language - to use the language to its advantage instead of simulating other languages.